# What is the name of the template to theme a reset password mail?

Tags: theming, emails

I want to theme the mail which is used to sent a link to user when the user forgot the password. I want to know what I need to name the template file so that Drupal will take my email template file.

I am using the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module. How do I find the key of that particular module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> mimemail-message--user-pasword-reset.tpl.php

template file name is not worked.Belowone worked for me

> mimemail-message--password_reset.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

```
mimemail-message--user-pasword-reset.tpl.php
```

this is how you should name the template file that will cover User Password Reset email.

More information here: [Theming HTML Mail sent through Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/node/958146)

I'd recommend installing [Mail Logger](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_logger). It shows the mail key of every email that is sent. Note: this module currently has only D7 release.

Answer (score 0):

use

> mimemail-message--user--password_reset.tpl.php

correct format mimemail-message--[module]--[key].tpl.php .
The module in this case is "user" (check yoursite/modules/user).
The keys can be found in the module's hook_mail() implementation,
in this case "password_reset"